# Microsoft Report Builder - Need to convert Charge Posted Period to previous month

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder

I am new to Report Builder and do not have all of the fields that I usually would have. I have a report that the filter currently is set to Charge Posted Period = 7 and Charge Posted Period = 2021.  I need to find a way to convert the Charge Posted Period to look to the last period/month so I can schedule the report to run.  I have tried multiple queries and functions which did not work.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PJOh.jpg)

Has anyone worked with this report builder and can guide me to correct this filter?

Note: The field Charge Posted Period is not a Date type field, I believe it is an aggregate type field.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the query for the Period parameter to be based on the year selected. Then your drop-down would only contain periods in that year.

```
SELECT [Charge Posted Period] AS AVAILABLE_VALUES, 
    MAX([Charge Posted Period])OVER() AS DEFAULT_VALUES
FROM TABLE 
WHERE [Charge Posted Year] = @ChargePostedYear
```